# Problemas ao utilizar Entrust com Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

Meu SO é **Linux**, instalei o Laravel 5.1 e estava **funcionando** corretamente.
Instalei via **artisan** o pacote Entrust e estava configurando o mesmo seguindo as instruções do README.md(https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) até chegar no ponto de executar o seguinte comando:

**php artisan vendor:publish**

Como resposta recebo o erro:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::isDeferred() in /var/www/html/fretesja/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 119
```

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::isDeferred()

Agora não está funionando mais o Laravel.

Conhecem alguma forma de contornar este problema e ter o Entrust funcionando?

Comment: Bom dia Alexandre, instalou no teu projeto ou baixou em um lugar aleatoriamente?

Comment: Instalei no meu projeto

Answer (score 0):

Precisa colocar isto nos *aliases* do `config/app.php`:

```
'Entrust' => 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade'
```

Comment: Isto é a solução do seu problema? Por que postou em inglês??

Comment: É a solução sim, coloquei na pressa não vi que estava em inglês.